# '$("#elementId").change()' is not working and '$(document).on("change" "elementId")' is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onchange

Lately it has happened to my web pages that even for the jsp page elements which are already there, `$("#elementId").change()` do not work but `$(document).on("change" "elementId"` does. Looks like page `document` is getting ready lazily and so direct event handlers on page elements are not getting added. Any tip?

ps: The elements I am talking about were not generated dynamically.

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/receipt.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/myCss.css" >
<title>Generate Report</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
<form:form action="getReceipt.html" commandName="viewQuote">
<div class="main_div">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td valign="top" align="left">
                Res Number
            </td>
            <td  valign="top" align="left" >
                <input id="reservatnNo" type="text" name="reservatnNo" value="">
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>
                <button id="generateReportButton" type="submit">
                    Submit Form
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</div>
</form:form>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
});


$(document).on("change", "#reservatnNo", function(event) {
//$('#reservatnNo').change(function(){
    alert("changeddd");
});
```

Comment: Can you share your code here ?

Comment: Does `#elementId` getting loaded dynamically.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy No, not dynamically as I said. I am simply invoking the web page from a previous web page using an anchor link.

Comment: @KrishR

How do I paste formatted code here? All I have is a limited comment box I am commenting in.

Comment: @user2918640, No need to add code in comment, you can always edit the question

Comment: You can copy paste the code in Question section and use of  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `$("#elementId").change()` is inside `$(document).ready()` function.

Otherwise $("#elementId") returns the empty jQuery object (as the control does not exist yet) and no event is registered.

Or outside `ready` method, one can use `$(document).on()` or the older method `$(document).bind()` to achieve the reliable event handling.

Comment: you could have comment this.

Comment: I know, putting inside ready is a practice. But I am curious how they were working outside ready, few days ago.

Comment: if you put it outside then there is risk of registering event for a control which is not yet created in DOM

Comment: I agree with you. But I am still curious how they were working outside.

Comment: @user2918640 The `bind` (although [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used!) form works outside because of [*delegated events*](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The event is actually *bound* to document. When the event triggers *against* the document element (through bubbling), jQuery will *at that time* check the event target against the selector (and when the event occurs the element exists and thus matches the selector).

Comment: (I agree that this is only a *partial* answer and should be expanded; it trivially explains why `$(..).change` *doesn't* work, but it doesn't explain why `$(..).bind/on` *does* work [with event delegation].)

Comment: @user2864740
Thanks for answering. I understand, I also read about jquery delegated events today. But still, there is nothing dynamic in my jsp document which might make my jsp document partially ready to execute simple events post page load. I think, I am missing something.

Comment: @user2918640 It doesn't matter if it's not dynamic - the script executes *before* the relevant DOM elements are created. Use a breakpoint (where the events are bound) and inspect `$("#reservatnNo").length` (it will be 0 because the element *does not yet exist* in the DOM). This is what `$(readyFn)` solves. Alternatively, move the relevant `<script>` so that it appears *after* the element in document order.

Comment: @user2864740 Well, that was helpful of you to state what's actually happening at the page load. I'll debug as you said to find out if it's actually so. For now, I'm getting along with $(document).on() version.  Thank you.